# server authentication without credentials file

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app with server authentication, exactly as follow

```
// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com")
    .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"))
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

turns out that the `serviceAccountCredentials.json` is in the gitignore, but I need to have this file in the server while building/deploying the app...
is there a way to do server auth without this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

#### Update (2016-08-16) from the [linked Google Group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/_6Rhro3zBbk/u8hB1oVRCgAJ):

> We just released version 3.3.0 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK... our Node.js SDK now supports the client-side auth and user management methods found in the web version of the SDK! That means you can authenticate your Node.js process using end-user credentials as well as manage user accounts.

Read the post for full details.

#### Previous (accepted) answer

Currently the only way to authenticate from a node.js server is by using the service account. We're working on expanding this.

See this [post on our firebase-talk group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/orKZRQZacsQ).